Why does my proof of the trapezoidal rule not yield the expected remainder term for a general interval?
I'm following Otto Forster's Analysis 1, where the trapezoidal rule on $[0, 1]$ is given by:
$$
\int_0^1 f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2}(f(0) + f(1)) - R
$$
with the remainder ( R ) being:
$$
R = \frac{1}{12} f''(\xi),
$$
where $\xi \in [0, 1]$.
I understand how to derive this for $[0, 1]$ using integration by parts and applying the mean value theorem for integrals. However, when I attempt to generalize this to an arbitrary interval $[a, b]$, I run into an issue with the remainder term.
Here’s what I’ve done:

I use the variable transformation $x \mapsto t(x) := (b-a)x + a$, which gives $\mathrm{d}t = (b-a)\, \mathrm{d}x$.

After this transformation, the integral becomes:
$$
   \int_0^1 f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t.
   $$

Applying the trapezoidal rule, I get the approximation:
$$
   \int_a^b f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t = \frac{b-a}{2} \left( f(a) + f(b) \right) - R.
   $$

However, the remainder I compute is:
$$
   R = \frac{b-a}{12} f''(\hat{\xi})
   $$
with $\hat{\xi} \in [a, b]$, instead of the expected $\frac{(b-a)^3}{12} f''(\hat{\xi})$.


Question:
Why does my derivation only give $\frac{b-a}{12} f''(\hat{\xi})$ for the remainder term instead of the expected $\frac{(b-a)^3}{12} f''(\hat{\xi})$? How should I modify my proof to correctly derive the remainder term for a general interval $[a, b]$?

You should give different names to the function before and after variable transformation. The issue is that you calculate the second derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$. In the final result you need the derivative with respect to $t$. Each time you differentiate introduces a factor of $b-a$ by the chain rule.

I had a feeling it has something to do with that. Let me check this out.

Yup, that's it. If you want to, you can write this as an answer and I'll be happy to mark it as the accepted one!

This issue probably arose because you denote two different functions by $f$ and distinguish them only by the name of their variables.
Let $g \colon [0,1] \to \mathbf R$ be defined by $g(t) = f(a + (b-a)t)$. As you correctly pointed out, the trapezoidal rule for $[0,1]$ yields
\begin{align*}
\int_a^bf(x) \mathrm d x 
&= (b-a)\int_0^1g(t) \mathrm dt\\
&= (b-a)\left(\frac{g(0) + g(1)}2 + R\right)\\
&= \frac{b-a}2(f(a) + f(b)) + (b-a)R
\end{align*}
where $R = \frac1{12}g''(\tau)$ for some $\tau \in [0,1]$. By the chain rule, we get $R = \frac1{12}(b-a)^2f''(a + (b-a)\tau) = \frac{(b-a)^2}{12}f''(\xi)$, where $\xi = a + (b-a)\tau \in [a,b]$.
You were missing the two factors of $b-a$ arising from the chain rule here. When transforming the domain of a function, remember that derivatives change in a more complicated way than the original function. You should give new names to the transformed functions in the future to avoid such issues.
